# Storing image in mongoose gobbles the data

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Have a bit of an issue, and not even really certain where to begin. 
I'm using ng-file-upload to upload the file. The file turn up on the server, storing it in a file temporary. Checking it I can open it and it is still a jpg file (if that is the file is).

So pretty certain it is the save to the database itself that is causing the issue. 
In short, I read the file, using base64 encoding, then stores it to the schema:

```
router.post('/rest/imgupload', multipartyMiddleware, function(req, res, next){
    var file = req.files.file;
    console.log(file.name);
    console.log(file.type);
    file.owner = req.user.id;
    for( var i in file){
        console.log("ID " + i + " DATA: " +file[i]);
    }

    fs.readFile(file.path, 'base64', function(err,data){
        if(err){
            log.error("File read error: "+err)
            res.status(500).send("Internal server error!")
        } else {
            //file.data=Buffer(data).toString('base64');
            //console.log("This is what comes out" + data);
            var Image = new mgImage(file);
            Image.save(function(err,doc){
                if(err){
                    log.error("Database write error: " + err);
                    res.status(500).send("Internal server error!")
                } else {
                    log.info("Deleting file: " + file.path)
                    //fs.unlink(file.path, function(err){
                    //    if(err){
                    //        log.error("Failed to delete file: " + file.path)
                    //        res.status(500).send("Internal server error!")
                    //    } else{
                    res.status(201).send({ imageId: doc._id })
                    //    }
                    //})
                }
            })
        }
    })


});
```

To store the data itself I use a buffer as follows:

```
var sketchSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    size: String,
    type: String,
    data: {
        type: Buffer,
        required: true
    },
    owner: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
});
```

However, if I try to use it as a picture using base64 encoding 
 it fails. And it seems like the data stored in data is just not a jpeg image.

Any suggestions on what I am missing, or at least what on earth I am doing wrong.

Comment: I also doublechecked by creating the image, then manually update it to a base64 encoded file, and the rest of the code works. So whatever I am doing wrong, it seems to be connected to how I read the file into the database, whatever is stored in BinData 0 under data is not a base64 encoded image.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, do not attempt to tell the fs.read to read the files as 'base64'

Change this line:

```
fs.readFile(file.path, 'base64', function(err,data){
```

to

```
fs.readFile(file.path, function(err,data){
```

Then just set the image to
image.data=data //the raw data from the file, no need to encode it as base64 it seems.